# Javascript Error with Onload and onmouseout events

Tags: javascript, html, function, onload, onmouseout

I am trying to execute code when the onmuseout/onload events occur, but for some reason my code is not running??

```js
function outFunction() {
  document.getElementById("mouseout").alert("Don't Leave!")
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = "This DIV is loaded."
}
```

```html
<div onmouseout="outFunction()" , id="mouseout">DIV</div>
<div id="hi" onload="myFunction()"></div>
```

Comment: What do you expect `document.getElementById("mouseout").alert("Don't Leave!")` to do?

Comment: Make an alert pop up saying "Don't Leave!"

Comment: If you want to show an alert, just use `alert("Don't Leave!")`. `alert` is not a function on the `div` that `getElementById` is returning.

Answer (score 0):

#### outFunction:

The `alert` function is on `window` (or the implicit `global` object). It is **not** on the returned `div` element (which is an instance of `HTMLDivElement`).

Change your function to this:

```
function outFunction() {
    window.alert("Don't Leave!")
}
```

Note that this also works (the same `alert` function is being used, because `window` is the `global` object):

```
function outFunction() {
    alert("Don't Leave!")
}
```

#### myFunction:

`onload` is not defined on `HTMLDivElement`. You should use `document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', handler )` instead.

Change your HTML and JavaScript function to this:

```
<div id="hi"></div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = "This DIV is loaded."
}
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', myFunction ); // Do NOT put parentheses! i.e. don't put `myFunction()`, just put `myFunction` - because you're passing a function-reference, not a function-call.
```